# Problem: Sublime Text 3 are always create new document in Lunux

Tags: sublime-text

I have a problem. Sublime Text 3 are always create two files on startap
- untitled document
- Document

If I close this tabs ST3 are create them again in next launch.

Here is the screen cast https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vjLXvfB_wY0
Please help me how can I fix that? I can't found anything about this bug in ST3 settings.

OS: Ubuntu LInux 15.10
Sublime Text 3, 3083